# getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while adding a button to layout

Tags: java, javafx, invocationtargetexception

I am totally new in javafx!!
I tried a very very simple code and I got stuck.
when I tried to add a button to the layout It does not work.
I know this question may be too simple but I really do not know how to fix it.
I would appreciated if you could help me.
This is my code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Test extends Application{

    Button button;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("Title");
        StackPane layout = new StackPane();

        button = new Button();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

and I got the error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x46b3f4cf) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x46b3f4cf
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
    at Test.start(Test.java:21)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application Test
```

Comment: What version of JavaFX are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the error I'm assuming you're using JavaFX 11 (or at least JavaFX 9+). Note that the ultimate problem is *not* the `InvocationTargetException` but the `IllegalAccessError`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelper (in unnamed module @0x46b3f4cf) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x46b3f4cf
```

This is telling you code in the "unnamed module" is  trying to access internals of the `javafx.graphics` module. As this is not allowed the error is thrown. But the real problem here is that `ControlHelper` is in the unnamed module but it's *supposed* to be in the `javafx.controls` module, if the package name is anything to go by. This problem is caused by having `javafx.graphics` on the *modulepath* but `javafx.controls` on the *classpath*.

Make sure you have both modules (and `javafx.base`) on the `--module-path`. As your code is not modular (no `module-info` file) you will also have to tell the module system to resolve it by using:

```
--add-modules javafx.controls
```

You don't have to include `javafx.graphics` in the `--add-modules` command because `javafx.controls` requires `javafx.graphics` (and `javafx.graphics` requires `javafx.base`). As all modules are on the modulepath they will be resolved.

How you set these commands is dependent on how you launch your application (e.g. command-line, IDE, Maven, Gradle, etc...).

If you ever make your code modular you won't need to use the `--add-modules` command, just put the appropriate `requires` directives in your `module-info` file. For example:

```
module app {
    requires javafx.controls;
}
```