# The class SwingNode in openjfx causes problems

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I wanted to migrate my JavaFX app to JDK 11 & OpenJFX and I noticed that SwingNode causes problems. I decided to create new project and see what's going on. 
Interestingly, when I change to JDK 8, everything is fine.
In newer version, errors appear. I don't know what it's due to.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        // problem
        final SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper (in unnamed module @0x412b4fb) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x412b4fb
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.<clinit>(SwingNode.java:143)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:20)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

VM options:
--module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: Post how you run your app with Java 11 (VM options, module-path, add-modules...)

Comment: VM options: --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: And what about adding the `javafx.swing` [module](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.swing/module-summary.html)? It contains the `SwingNode`. You need to include it as well.

Comment: It works. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of that stack trace is the last `Caused by:`, which is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper (in unnamed module @0x412b4fb) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to unnamed module @0x412b4fb
```

This says there's a class, named `SwingNodeHelper`, in the "unnamed module" which extends a class, named `NodeHelper`, present in the `javafx.graphics` module. The `javafx.graphics` module, however, does not export this superclass (more specifically, the package to which the superclass belongs) to the "unnamed module". This leads to the `IllegalAccessError` when trying to load the `SwingNodeHelper` class.

The "unnamed module" is a special `Module` (one per `ClassLoader`) which contains the classes on the *classpath*. The `SwingNode` and related `SwingNodeHelper` classes are part of the `javafx.swing` module. This knowledge, combined with the given error, tells us the `javafx.swing` module is being used from the *classpath* when it needs to be used from the *modulepath*. The fix, as stated by José Pereda in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874607/the-class-swingnode-in-openjfx-causes-problems/55876672#comment98409148_55874607), is to include the `javafx.swing` module in your `--add-modules` command.

The reason this works is because the `javafx.graphics` modules *does* export the needed package to the `javafx.swing` module—but everything needs to be on the *modulepath* in order to work properly.

When, or if, you make your code modular you can forgo the `--add-modules` command and simply list the appropriate `requires` directives in your `module-info.java` file.

```
module <your-module-name> {
    requires javafx.swing;
    // other directives...
}
```

---

Related questions:

- [Module error when running JavaFx media application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53237287/module-error-when-running-javafx-media-application)
- [getting java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException while adding a button to layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54138287/getting-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception-while-adding-a-button-to-lay)
- [JavaFX 11: IllegalAccessError when creating Label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291958/javafx-11-illegalaccesserror-when-creating-label)