# JavaFX SwingNode instantiation fails with exception

Tags: javafx

I'm working with a new JavaFX project. I have legacy Swing control panels.  When I try to do `new SwingNode`, I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check
failed: class com.sun.javafx.embed.swing.SwingNodeHelper (in unnamed
module @0x35dc99d5) cannot access class
com.sun.javafx.scene.NodeHelper (in module javafx.graphics) because
module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene to
unnamed module @0x35dc99d5
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode.<clinit>(SwingNode.java:135)
    at test.app.MJFXtest.start(MJFXtest.java:11)
```

This is on JavaFX v21. I tried 19, but still the same.

---

```
package test.app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;

public class MJFXtest extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    SwingNode sn = new SwingNode();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     launch(args);
  }
}
```

---

I expect this not to throw an exception on the new SwingNode(); line, but to create a new SwingNode.

I saw this Q/A about the same problem, but I have javafx-swing included in my pom file.
([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55874607/the-class-swingnode-in-openjfx-causes-problems](https://stackoverflow.com))
This is the javafx section from pom.xml and it looks like all the relevant libraries are there.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

Full commmand line:

````
d:; cd 'd:\Thomas\Dropbox\Projects\morbid'; & 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:51624' '@C:\Users\Thomas\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_a1x3p1tfjwls6nptiscdinmdj.argfile' 'com.bobandthomas.morbid.MorbidJFX'```

and full pom.xml
````

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bobandthomas.morbid</groupId>
    <artifactId>morbid</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-web -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx</artifactId>
            <version>21</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.vecmath/vecmath -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.vecmath</groupId>
            <artifactId>vecmath</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>toxi</groupId>
            <artifactId>geom</artifactId>
            <version>0021</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>D:\Thomas\toxiclibs\toxiclibscore.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>toxi</groupId>
            <artifactId>volume</artifactId>
            <version>0021</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>D:\Thomas\toxiclibs\volumeutils.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.bobandthomas.morbid.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine> --add-exports javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application=ALL-UNNAMED </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is essentially the same error as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53237287/6395627), except for you it's about `javafx.swing` instead of `javafx.media`. As for why the `javafx.swing` module is not being put on the module path while the other JavaFX modules are, I'm not sure. Could you show your full POM and share the exact command you use to run your application?

Comment: Also, what happens if you remove the `org.openjfx:javafx` dependency? I don't believe that's necessary, anyway.